# Resolving TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Tags: python, django, django-models, int

A few people on Stack Overflow have already discussed this problem but none of the answers were any help to me.

This is post_2

```
post_2 = Post(title = 'Dark Knight', content='Batman was amazing in the Dark Knight', author_id=User.id)
```

This is the contents of models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I do

```
>>> post_2.save()
```

I get the error

```
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
```

Here is the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 937, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 959, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\HP\project2_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 968, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
```

Comment: What is `User` in your code line?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `User` instance.

```
author_id=User.id
```

Asks for the `id` field on the `User` class.  You need something more like:

```
author = User(...)
post_2 = Post(title='Dark Knight', content='Batman was amazing in the Dark Knight', author=author)
post_2.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for every ones help, I had not put `.first()` when I assigned a value to `user`

```
user = User.objects.filter(username='Batman').first()
```